# Using Ansible docker_container, how can I display standard out? (stdout)

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm using Ansible and its module `docker_container` to launch tape unit test containers in nodejs.  This is nice because I don't have to have npm mess up my host, my only dev box dependency is python and docker.

I need to be able to see `stdout` to see that tests have been run.  However, Docker's `--attach` option is not exposed in `docker_container` and I cannot find any way to have `stdout` print out from the ansible launch of the container.

I can go back to bash scripts to launch docker containers but I'd rather not...

How can I display a container's standard out with Ansible's docker_container module?

Comment: it's back to bash scripts.   Prettified output is dead with any solution I can come up with, there are horrible races using ansible, I have to recompile the docker image every time anyways.... probably overkill to use ansible for this use case.

Answer (score 22):

This actually works with Ansible v2.5, by using the `detach` attribute:

```
- name: Run the tests
  docker_container:
    detach: false
    name: "foo-container"
    command: npm test
  register: docker_container_output

- name: Show test output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ docker_container_output.ansible_facts.docker_container.Output }}"

- name: Remove the test container
  docker_container:
    state: absent
    name: "foo-container"
```

It's important to specify `detach: false` to capture the output, and then to use the `ansible_facts.docker_container.Output` path to access the results.

Comment: For ansible 2.10 try 
debug: var=docker_container_output.container.Output
or even
debug: var=docker_container_output

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Ansible for running simple unit tests.  Ansible makes complicated things easy and easy things complicated.

The following bash script is 4 lines and the Ansible playbook is already at 25 lines and still not fully functional due to concurrency issues and output formatting issues (I'm sure I'd find more).

Ansible for docker is still too new, doesn't deal easily with concurrency issues, has missing docker features, etc. and probably should only be used when you are doing something complicated that bash can't easily handle (like dealing with remote servers, retries, etc)

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t server-unit-test .
docker run -it --name server-unit-test server-unit-test npm test
docker rm server-unit-test
```

Comment: You make a valid point as I ran into similar problems.
I ended up moving this to jenkins.. . had it run ansible to set it up.. THEN call the script so I had much better control over the logging.

Answer (score -3):

You can see logs for docker container using this command... `docker logs containerName` . To print logs according to their level like TRACE, INFO etc, try supervisord .

Comment: not a complete answer, because ansible still swallows all stdout

Comment: there's also a race condition between the tasks `docker logs` and `docker_container`.  Often `docker_logs` wins...

Comment: and in further news, ansible completely broke the 'wait' functionality as documented in 'Ansible Up and Running' Oreilly book.  Uhoh.